# Regular expression to match HTML table row ( <tr> ) NOT containing a specific value

Tags: html, regex, html-table, notepad++, tablerow

I'm using Notepad++ to clean up a long and messy HTML table, and
I'm trying to use regular expressions.

I need to remove all the table rows that **don't contain** a specific value (may I call that *substring*?).

After having all the file contents unwrapped, I've been able to use the following regular expression to select, one by one, every table row **with all its contents**:

```
<tr>.+?</tr>
```

How can I improve the regular expression in order to select and replace only table rows containing, somewhere inside a `<td>` part of them, that defined *substring*?

I don't know if this does matter but the structure of every table row is the following (I've put there every HTML tag, the dots stand for standard content/values)

```
<tr>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> <a sfref="..." href="...">!! SUBSTRING I HAVE TO MATCH HERE !!</a> </td>
    <td> <img /> </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a specific string (if, so can't you just include that in your regular expression)?  Or looking for any content inside of an anchor tag?

Comment: It's 2012. Stop trying to parse HTML with regular expressions. Use an XML parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: This question is well-formulated. I don't think the downvotes are reasonable because the question itself is fine.

Answer (score 6):

You should rather write a little script in a programming language that contains a simple DOM parser, because no regex solution can ever be perfect.

Also, your question seems a bit contradictory to me. First you say, you want to remove all rows that **don't** contain a specific substring. Then you say you want to match all rows that **do** contian a specific substring.

Anyway, here is a regex makeshift solution for both cases. To ensure `SUBSTRING` occurs inside a row, you need to use this:

```
<tr>((?!</tr>).)+?SUBSTRING.+?</tr>
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. It might not be supported before Notepad++ 6, so make sure you update. The lookahead makes sure that never go past the end of one table row, just to find `SUBSTRING` in the next one. It does this by asserting for every single character in our `+?` repetition, that it does not mark the beginning of `</tr>`.

To ensure that `SUBSTRING` does not occur inside the row, we can simply put `SUBSTRING` into that negative lookahead we already have:

```
<tr>((?!SUBSTRING).)+?</tr>
```

Note that both solutions will start to crumble if you have additional whitespace in your tags or attributes in the opening tags, and similar things. Which is why a solution using a DOM parser is highly recommended.